# Clang failed to compile with unused template

Tags: c++, templates, clang

There is some code in our codebase that failed to compile with clang10. The code looks like this:

```cpp
class A {
private:
    A& operator=(const A&);  // don't allow assignment operator
    A(const A&);  // don't allow default copy constructor
};



template<class T>
class pool_allocator {

    void setAllocator(A* a) { allocator = *a; }
    A& getAllocator() const { return allocator; }

protected:
    pool_allocator& operator=(const pool_allocator&) { return *this; }
    A& allocator;
};
```

And this is the error message:

```
test.cpp:13:41: error: 'operator=' is a private member of 'A'
    void setAllocator(A* a) { allocator = *a; }
                              ~~~~~~~~~ ^ ~~
test.cpp:4:8: note: declared private here
    A& operator=(const A&);  // don't allow assignment operator
       ^
1 error generated.
```

However, in xcode-version clang, the code actually compiles. It also compiles in visual studio 2015. I guess that's because the template is not actually used.

I also found the with this parameter `-fdelayed-template-parsing` the code also compiles with clang10.

So why clang10 report the error even the template is unused? Is this expected? and is `-fdelayed-template-parsing` the correct parameter to skip this error?

NOTE: the clang10 is install on macOS Catalina with macports.

Comment: `setAllocator` is independent of `T`. I would says ill-formed NDR. and clang10 succeeds to diagnose.

Comment: @Jarod42 but then xcode-version clang and visual studio compile without issue. So it's undefined?

Comment: *Non-dependent names are looked up and bound at the point of template definition.* in  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name

Comment: @kkpattern they always do something against standard.

Comment: NDR stands for No Diagnostic Required, (as it might be hard, impossible to detect in general cases).

Comment: Correct fix would be to remove `setAllocator` or implement it in a correct way (at least for one `T`).

Comment: @Jarod42 *If the meaning of a non-dependent name changes between the definition context and the point of instantiation of a specialization of the template, the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.* why do you think it's IFNDR? nothing is changed between the points of definition and instantiation. it's just ill-formed, IMO.

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks for explaining NDR to me. Unfortunately, the code is actually in a third-base library which shared in multip project in our company so it's not very convenient to fix. Maybe that's why Xcode and the visual studio team decide to let it go.

Comment: @RedFog: there are no possible instantiations making the method correct. -> IFNDR.

Comment: @kkpattern: Do you have access to `A` code? Adding `friend pool_allocator<struct Dummy>;` should be enough as workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [temp#res.general-6.1](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp#res.general-6.1)

> The program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required, if:
>
> - (6.1)
>   no valid specialization can be generated for a template or a substatement of a constexpr if statement within a template and the template is not instantiated, or

`void setAllocator(A* a) { allocator = *a; }`
is wrong for any `T`, so program is Ill-Formed No Diagnostic Required (IFNDR).

> why clang10 report the error even the template is unused?
>
> Is this expected?

clang10 appears to diagnose that issue.

diagnotic is not required, so it depends of "quality" of implementation.

> and is `-fdelayed-template-parsing` the correct parameter to skip this error?

Correct way is to fix the error.

Remove `setAllocator` or rewrite it (including changing `A`) in a way that the code is correct for at least one `T`.

Comment: The original third-party lib removed the `setAllocator`: https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glslang/commit/24b3e8384e93f3e73b6aa14ea00a30574112f9ba